# Python Dash_ empty scatter plot with callbacks

Tags: plotly, plotly-dash

I am new to python and dash. I came from C++ background.
I am following tutorial 3 “[Basic Dash Callbacks](https://dash.plot.ly/getting-started-part-2)”. And I wanted to do scatter or (Scatter3d) on “[gapminderDataFiveYear.csv](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv)” with multiple ‘drop down’ and ‘radio items’. But I tried many times however the data is not showing in the scatter plot. Please help with bugs in the code below:

```html
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import webbrowser as wb
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np
#

df = pd.read_csv(
    'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/'
    'datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv')
df.to_csv('test.csv')
df = pd.read_csv('./test.csv')
df['test'] = np.random.randint (10, 100, size = len(df))
col_to_choose = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.float64].columns.values.tolist()
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'xaxis-column',
                options = [{'label' : i, 'value': i} for i in col_to_choose],    
                value = 'pop'
            ),  
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id = 'xaxis-type',
                options = [{'label' : i, 'value' : i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value = 'Linear',
                labelStyle = {'display':'inline-block'}
            )
        ],
        style = {'width' : '48%', 'display' : 'inline-block'}),

        html.Div([
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id = 'yaxis-column',
                options = [{'label' : i, 'value': i} for i in col_to_choose],    
                value = 'gdpPercap'
            ),  
            dcc.RadioItems(
                id = 'yaxis-type',
                options = [{'label' : i, 'value' : i} for i in ['Linear', 'Log']],
                value = 'log',
                labelStyle = {'display':'inline-block'}
            )
        ],
        style = {'width' : '48%', 'display' : 'inline-block'}),
    ]),
    
    dcc.Graph(id = 'graph-practice'),
    
    dcc.Slider(
        id = 'year-slider',
        min = df['year'].min(),
        max = df['year'].max(),
        value = df['year'].max(),
        step = None,
        marks = {str(year):str(year) for year in df ['year'].unique()}
    )
])


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('graph-practice', 'figure'),
    
    [dash.dependencies.Input('xaxis-column', 'value'),     
     dash.dependencies.Input('yaxis-column', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('xaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('yaxis-type', 'value'),
     dash.dependencies.Input('year-slider', 'value')
    ]
)
def update_graph(xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name,
                 xaxis_type, yaxis_type,
                 year_value):
    dff = df[df.Year == year_value]
    
    return {
        'data' : [go.Scatter(
            x = dff['xaxis_column_name'].values,
            y = dff['yaxis_column_name'].values,
            text = dff['country'],
            mode = 'markers',
            marker = {
                'size' : 15,
                'opacity' :0.5,
                'line': {'width': 0.5, 'color': 'white'}
            }
        )],
        'layout' : go.Layout(
            xaxis = {
                'title': xaxis_column_name,
                'type' : 'linear' if xaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
                
            },
            yaxis = {
                'title': yaxis_column_name,
                'type' : 'linear' if yaxis_type == 'Linear' else 'log'
                
            },
            margin = {'l' : 40, 'b': 40, 't':10, 'r':0},
            hovermode = 'closest'
        )
    }


if __name__ == '__main__':
    wb.open_new('http://127.0.0.1:8050/')    
    app.run_server(debug = False)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfC9q.png)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems

The first is this:

```
dff = df[df.Year == year_value]
```

`df` doesn't have a `Year` column, but it does have a `year` column ([source data](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv))

---

The second problem is this

```
x = dff['xaxis_column_name'].values
y = dff['yaxis_column_name'].values
```

These columns also don't exist. In this case you're trying to pass the `xaxis_column_name` and `yaxis_column_name` parameters from the callback, but you need to pass the variables without the surrounding quotes.

---

Full example:

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import numpy as np
import webbrowser as wb
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv(
    "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/plotly/"
    "datasets/master/gapminderDataFiveYear.csv"
)
df.to_csv("test.csv")
df = pd.read_csv("./test.csv")
df["test"] = np.random.randint(10, 100, size=len(df))
col_to_choose = df.loc[:, df.dtypes == np.float64].columns.values.tolist()
app = dash.Dash()

app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Div(
            [
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="xaxis-column",
                            options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in col_to_choose],
                            value="pop",
                        ),
                        dcc.RadioItems(
                            id="xaxis-type",
                            options=[
                                {"label": i, "value": i} for i in ["Linear", "Log"]
                            ],
                            value="Linear",
                            labelStyle={"display": "inline-block"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "48%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
                html.Div(
                    [
                        dcc.Dropdown(
                            id="yaxis-column",
                            options=[{"label": i, "value": i} for i in col_to_choose],
                            value="gdpPercap",
                        ),
                        dcc.RadioItems(
                            id="yaxis-type",
                            options=[
                                {"label": i, "value": i} for i in ["Linear", "Log"]
                            ],
                            value="log",
                            labelStyle={"display": "inline-block"},
                        ),
                    ],
                    style={"width": "48%", "display": "inline-block"},
                ),
            ]
        ),
        dcc.Graph(id="graph-practice"),
        dcc.Slider(
            id="year-slider",
            min=df["year"].min(),
            max=df["year"].max(),
            value=df["year"].max(),
            step=None,
            marks={str(year): str(year) for year in df["year"].unique()},
        ),
    ]
)


@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output("graph-practice", "figure"),
    [
        dash.dependencies.Input("xaxis-column", "value"),
        dash.dependencies.Input("yaxis-column", "value"),
        dash.dependencies.Input("xaxis-type", "value"),
        dash.dependencies.Input("yaxis-type", "value"),
        dash.dependencies.Input("year-slider", "value"),
    ],
)
def update_graph(
    xaxis_column_name, yaxis_column_name, xaxis_type, yaxis_type, year_value
):
    dff = df[df.year == year_value]

    return {
        "data": [
            go.Scatter(
                x=dff[xaxis_column_name].values,
                y=dff[yaxis_column_name].values,
                text=dff["country"],
                mode="markers",
                marker={
                    "size": 15,
                    "opacity": 0.5,
                    "line": {"width": 0.5, "color": "white"},
                },
            )
        ],
        "layout": go.Layout(
            xaxis={
                "title": xaxis_column_name,
                "type": "linear" if xaxis_type == "Linear" else "log",
            },
            yaxis={
                "title": yaxis_column_name,
                "type": "linear" if yaxis_type == "Linear" else "log",
            },
            margin={"l": 40, "b": 40, "t": 10, "r": 0},
            hovermode="closest",
        ),
    }


if __name__ == "__main__":
    wb.open_new("http://127.0.0.1:8050/")
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```